# How to get SAML Assertion from Okta API in any other format except HTML

Tags: saml, okta, okta-api, idp

I am developing an application and would like to use Okta as the Identity Provider (IdP) to log in to AWS. I am searching for Okta APIs that I can use to obtain the Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) assertion in a json or other format, excluding HTML.

I have discovered that I need to use a POST request to "/api/v1/authn" to obtain the session token, followed by a GET request to "/home/[APP_NAME]/[APP_ID]?onetimetoken=[SESSION_TOKEN]" with the token received from the first call. Is this the only way to obtain the SAML Assertion?

Since the second call retrieves an HTML response that I would need to parse to obtain the SAML response, I suspect that there may be other APIs that I am unaware of that would allow me to obtain the SAML response in a better way.

Could someone assist me in finding the correct Okta API for this task?

Comment: Have you considered Okta to AWS Cognito integration instead?

Comment: No, I haven't. My. use-case is to authenticate users to AWS using Okta as an external credential provider using SAML workflow

Comment: But you are oversimplifying... If you are developing an app, you want your users to be authenticated to use this app, no? That's why I suggested to use Cognito, as your users will be authenticated with Okta and then Okta will assert their identity to AWS Cognito. If you don't want to go this path, you need to look at Okta AWS Account federation integration - https://www.okta.com/integrations/aws-account-federation/

Comment: I don't want to use Cognito as that will add another dependency in my project. I am following the Okta AWS Account federation integration with SAML only, but the thing is that I need programatic access because the product I am working on does not have any interface, instead it is a simple java program. So in order to get the credential’s from AWS STS, I need to parse the HTML and get the SAML Response which is then sent to STS service to get the temporary credentials.

Comment: I think you need to clarify: do you need an SSO into your app or into AWS? If it's the former then all you need is just to accep SAML assertion and act as SAML SP, it's relatively easy and there are tons of guides on how to do that. You don't need to go and explicitly programmatically do anything with Okta. Just initiate SAML SP login flow and Okta will do everything to authenticate a user and then send a user back to your app with a SAML assertion (response).

Comment: My goal is to retrieve Okta SAML token from Okta web API programmatically. We have and api called api/v1/authn which gives us the Session Token, we can use this API to get a SAML Response but that response is inside an HTML page. 
What I am confirming is that do we have any API which gives me a JSON response instead of an HTML page.

Comment: There is no way for you to get it through web API, b/c it does not exist. Currently SAML assertion is sent to an application through a front-end (browser) redirection

Comment: @Prateek What did you end up doing?  We have a similar use-case that Okta Solution Architect said be possible, but I have not been able to get it to work yet.